# How to override private method and property from superclass in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance

Using libraries from cocoapods, I want to override some private methods without messing up the library.

**ClassInLibrary.h**

```
@interface ClassInLibrary : UIView     
- (void)publicMethod;
@end
```

**ClassInLibrary.m**

```
@interface ClassInLibrary ()   
@property BOOL privateBoolean;   
@end   
@implementation ClassInLibrary  
- (void)privateMethod {
    ...
}
- (void)publicMethod {
    ...
    self.privateBoolean = YES;
    [self privateMethod];
}    
@end
```

What I am trying to do is create a subclass of `ClassInLibrary` and override the `publicMethod`. However, as `aBoolean` and `privateMethod` are not visible, are there any ways to override `publicMethod` as I need to use them?

**Subclass.m**

```
@interface Subclass ()    
@end    
@implementation Subclass
- (void)publicMethod {
    ...
    self.privateBoolean = NO; // cannot access
    [self privateMethod]; // cannot access
}   
@end
```

EDIT:

I agreed with @Anoop Vaidya, it is not a good idea to call private API. The real case is a hardcoded string in the public method and I want to modify it.

Superclass.m

```
- (void)publicMethod {
    ...
    [self privateMethod];
    ...
    NSString *string = @"a string";
    [self doSomeThingWithTheString]; // private
    ...
}
```

I can't use the `[super publicMethod]` as it will call the `privateMethod` again.
May be there are better and safer approaches to achieve this?

Comment: Private methods are private for a reason. You might be better off posting what you actually want to achieve. That said, you can try adding a category method instead of subclassing.

Comment: this.privateBoolean shouldn't be self.privateBoolean? And [super privateMethod] might work, I think obj-c will not prevent it. An introspection with respondsToSelector would be good to use in that case.

Comment: no this keyword in obj-c. And no access to private ivars in category.

Comment: Oops.. too much Android, edited

Comment: Can you edit the library and raise a pull request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can do as below, but you should not do.**

You can call the private method by using selectors, but it will show you a warning which you can  disable.

```
    SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"privateMethod");
    if ([a respondsToSelector:selector]) {
        NSLog(@"yes privateMethod exists");
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
        [self performSelector:selector];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer and I agree with you, I have added some information :)

Comment: May I ask why we should not do this?

Comment: @Thedude: Bad programming!!! private methods/variables were meant to be hidden and not to be accessed from outside world. You are doing hacking kind of stuff if you do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a category, defined in your subclass, but on the superclass, to make the property and method definition visible to the subclass. Now you can override the public method and use the private parts.

You still need to be careful as, if the private parts are changed / moved / renamed in the future your code will compile just fine. So, when doing this kind of thing your code should be defensive and generate good meaningful errors so you know what happened. Also ensure that this area is covered by unit / regression tests.

Comment: Thanks for you answer and I agree with you, I have added some information :)